# Incomplete animation of custom parameters in CAMetalLayer-backed view

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, calayer, metal

I have a view backed by a subclass of CAMetalLayer which needs to redraw its content in response to pinch and pan gestures. The layer has a handful of custom properties which are converted into a transformation matrix and which reveal and transition between two different drawing styles (`displayMode`). I'm not using a CADisplayLink-based animation loop, but I do need to do several different explicit animations of these custom attributes.

### The layer subclass

The custom-attribute code looks something like this, inspired by
 [this objc.io article](https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animating-custom-layer-properties/):

```
@implementation RHLayer

@dynamic origin;
@dynamic scale;
@dynamic rotation;
@dynamic reveal;
@dynamic transition;
@dynamic displayMode;

- (RHLayer *)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setUpRenderPipeline];
        self.scale = 1.0;
        self.reveal = 1.0;
        self.transition = 0.0;
        self.displayMode = RHSpokeMode;
        self.vertexData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:32768];
        self.indexData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:32768];
        [self.vertexData increaseLengthBy:32768];
        [self.indexData increaseLengthBy:32768];
        self.presentsWithTransaction = YES;
        self.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    return self;
}

- (RHLayer *)initWithLayer: (RHLayer *)layer {
    self = [super initWithLayer:layer];
    self.origin = layer.origin;
    self.scale = layer.scale;
    self.rotation = layer.rotation;
    self.reveal = layer.reveal;
    self.transition = layer.transition;
    self.displayMode = layer.displayMode;
    return self;
}

static NSSet *_animatableKeys = nil;

+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key {
    if (!_animatableKeys) {
        _animatableKeys = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"origin", @"scale", @"rotation",
                           @"reveal", @"transition", @"displayMode", nil];
    }
    if ([_animatableKeys member:key] ) {
        return YES;
    }
    return [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
}
```

So far I'm not implementing `actionForKey:` because I'm not (yet) interested in doing implicit animations, only explicit ones.

The drawing code looks like this:

```
- (id<CAMetalDrawable>)drawable {
    while (_drawable == nil) {
        _drawable = [self nextDrawable];
    }
    return _drawable;
}

- (void)display {
    [self update]; // Update transform matrix based on presentationLayer's current scale, origin, rotation

    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [self.commandQueue commandBuffer];
    id<CAMetalDrawable> drawable = self.drawable;
    MTLRenderPassDescriptor *rpd = [self renderPassDescriptorForTexture: drawable.texture];
    id<MTLRenderCommandEncoder> encoder = [commandBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:rpd];

    [encoder setRenderPipelineState: self.pipelineState];
    [encoder setVertexBuffer:self.vertexBuffer offset:0 atIndex:0];
    [encoder setVertexBuffer:self.uniformBuffer offset:0 atIndex:1];

    // ...
    // Draw metal primitives based on presentationLayer's current displayMode, reveal, transition
    // ...

    [encoder endEncoding];
    [commandBuffer commit];
    [commandBuffer waitUntilScheduled];
    [drawable present];
    self.drawable = nil;
}                                            

@end
```

### The view subclass

The companion UIView subclass is backed by the above layer subclass and contains the gesture recognizer logic, passing `scale`, `offset`, and `rotation` values to the layer as appropriate. (It also installs a UIButton subview, and will eventually install additional sublayers for text annotations on top of the backing layer.)

```
@implementation RHView

+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [RHLayer class];
}

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [super setFrame: frame];
    self.layer.drawableSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width * self.contentScaleFactor,
                                         self.bounds.size.height * self.contentScaleFactor);
}
```

So far, so good. The two drawing modes are working great, the transformation matrix is tracking perfectly with the gestures, and the button subview layout is tracking with the backing layer transformation.

### My problem

I'm having two distinct problems with my explicit animations:

**1.** `display` is always called exactly once with the new property value of the model layer before the animation starts. For example, here's a spring-back animation in the view code which enforces a minimum scale value:

```
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    if (self.layer.scale < 1.0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            CABasicAnimation *resetScale = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"scale"];
            resetScale.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: self.layer.scale];
            resetScale.toValue = @1.0;
            resetScale.duration = 0.2;
            resetScale.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
            self.layer.scale = 1.0;
            [self.layer addAnimation:resetScale forKey:@"ResetScale"];
        }];
    }
}
```

With this code, I get one frame with scale set to 1.0, then the next frame starts with the requested fromValue, and the animation continues from there. This results in an annoying visual pop.

**2.** The animation sometimes reaches the toValue, but sometimes doesn't. In the example above, on the last frame of animation `display` might end up getting called with a presentationLayer value of, say, 0.993 for `scale`, rather than 1.0. The model layer's value is definitely set to 1.0, but it takes a gestural nudge to force an additional redisplay with that value.

### Things I've tried

I've scoured dozens of SO articles and online tutorials, but I haven't come across an example where a CAMetalLayer is being directly subclassed.

- I've tried setting `presentsWithTransaction` to both YES and NO with no apparent effect. Ultimately I expect I'll need to use YES to animate my sublayers in sync with the backing layer, if I correctly understand what this setting does.
- For problem 1 above I've tried using `kCAFillModeBackwards` on the animation. No effect.
- For problem 2 above I've tried using a CATransaction with `[self setNeedsDisplay]` inside the completion block in order to force one additional `display` call. No luck there either.
- Various versions and reordering of the code inside my UIView animation block.
- My original version of the layer was a subclass of a standard CALayer which used CoreGraphics calls to do my custom drawing. That turned out to be way too slow to smoothly animate, so I rewrote with Metal. But even in that version I had the same problem with incomplete animations; that makes me suspect my problem has something to do with how I'm using custom properties, rather than something to do with using CAMetalLayer.

One other observation, possibly unrelated: in some occasional circumstance that I don't quite understand, `[self presentationLayer]` returns nil. So I'm doing things like the first line of this snippet (which gets called by `update`) in order to fall back to the model layer value:

```
- (matrix_float4x4)layerToViewTransform: (BOOL)animated {
    RadialHierarchyLayer *layer = animated && [self presentationLayer] ? [self presentationLayer] : self;

    matrix_float4x4 layerToView = matrix_float4x4_translation((vector_float3){ layer.origin.x, layer.origin.y, 0.0 });
    layerToView = matrix_multiply (layerToView, matrix_float4x4_rotateZ (layer.rotation));
    layerToView = matrix_multiply (layerToView, matrix_float4x4_uniform_scale (layer.scale));
    return layerToView;
}
```

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm working with a similar problem (I want to make a CAMetalLayer which uses CoreAnimation interpolation to redraw itself) and wondering if you ran into any gotchas here that you could share